# Alignment of struct didn't work with #pragma pack

Tags: c++, struct, pragma

I have a c++ structure:

```
struct a
{
     char b;
     int c;
     int d[100];
};
```

The size of the struct should be 405 bytes.
I saw that the size of the struct is 408 bytes. The reason is the alignment to 8 bytes after the integer "c". The array "d" should start at the 6th byte of the struct and not at the 9th byte.
I used `#pragma pack(1)` but it didn't solve the problem.
I cannot change the order of fields in the struct.
Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: With which compiler? On which system? Why do you need this?

Comment: Visual studio's default compiler.
Windows.
I need to send this struct to a remote computer

Comment: The problem is that I send a bigger struct than the desired size

Comment: Here is a idea serialize it and take into account endianess. Then let it be free over the network

Comment: Either send it field by filed, or use some serialization protocol (BSON, Google Protobuf, maybe boost.asio).

Comment: Using gcc 4.8 or clang 3.5 sizeof(a) is 405 bytes - with pragma pack directive.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: It's possible the OP would be better off with true serialization, but maybe not.  We don't have enough information to know that.  Suggesting Protobufs when the OP wanted to pack a structure is like killing an orange with a wooden stake.

Comment: It's 405 bytes in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013.  Perhaps you should show the code with the pack directives you're using.

Comment: Are you arguing over 3 bytes? This word is 4 bytes

Comment: You haven't shown the #pragma pack() directives you’re using.  They *should* work, so please show exactly what you used and where.

Answer (score 6):

The fault packing for most compilers I use is that objects align on their own size. The default packing for your struct would insert padding after the char and before the first int, to place that int on a 4 byte boundary. Obviously this is the behaviour you are seeing.

The code I use on Visual Studio to achieve packing looks like this.

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct a {
  char b;
  int c;
  int d[100];
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

It removes the padding, aligning the int on byte 1.

If I get some time I'll check it on a couple of versions of VS to confirm that, but my current code works exactly like this. This is how it's done, so the only question is why it isn't working for you.

EDIT: sizeof(a) is 405 as expected. Offset of b is 1. VS2012. Gcc is the same.